# Powershell и поля JSON объекта

Tags: json, powershell

День добрый. Работаю из Powershell с JSON, при выполнении определенных запросов, получаю результат в переменную $item :

```
{
   "_id":"idc",
   "reactions":{
      ":grin:":{
         "usernames":[
            "user1"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Не могу понять, как мне обратиться к объекту ":grin:", если в его имени - нечитаемые символы?
$resp.reactions.:grin: - по понятным причинам не работает.
Запрос выполняю с помощью :

```
$Url = "https://api.local"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Get
   if ($response.success) 
   { 
      foreach ($item in $response.messages) 
      {
        Write-Host $item.idc; # так можно
        Write-Host $item.reactions.:grin: #а так нельзя
      }
   }
```

Comment: с помощью чего ты работаешь с JSON?

Comment: Получаю результат с помощью $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Get

Comment: добавь необходимую информацию сразу в вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения можно указать имя поля в качестве строки, с помощью двойных кавычек:

```
$resp.reactions.":grin:"
```

Comment: Благодарю, это выглядит странно, но работает.